# plotting a 3 column data from 2 text files in a single plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I was trying to plot multiple data files in a single plot using gnuplot. Using "plot" it is fairly simple. However, using "splot", the required output is not coming through. The text files I am working with, are of the following form:

```
0 0 23

0 1 10

0 2 43

0 3 20
```

and so on. The plt file I made (not including the details of axes for the time being) was:

```
set pm3d map

splot "first.txt" using 1:2:3,\

      "second.txt" using 1:2:3
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem when using pm3d is that you need to have two distinct values in x and y to generate one colored square. That means, if you have a data file

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

you get one square with the corners being (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1) and by default a color value of 0.5 (average of the corners third column). So if e.g. all your x-values are zero, pm3d will not work.

You could try plotting your data without pm3d, and if this also fails, the reason is within your data files.

Does gnuplot give you any specific errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have that blank line after the backslash.